Msi Motherboard Shuts Down My Mouse And Keyboard
Please don't take offense, but I'm only looking for die hard savvy geeks who don't try to control me and tell me what to use on my own computer.
I do NOT want to switch to Windows 10 and I have many reasons for this I won't discuss in public, but will say it's ALL about CONTROL. I don't care about the propaganda spread worldwide about "end of life," so there's no need in trying to convince me.
Due to a previous desktop with an older MB, DDR 3 memory, etc. no longer working due to crashes because I think the computer store broke the MB when they put my hardware together (it had been in pieces when I moved from overseas to Mexico where finding good geeks is very difficult), I had to buy all new hardware except the HDs & power supply.
I purchased the MSI MAG B550 TOMAHAWK AM4 AMD B550 SATA 6Gb/s USB 3.0 ATX AMD Motherboard.
When I took it to another computer guy (different city) he said Win 7 wouldn't work on it. I freaked out at my website coder since he's the one who told me what to buy, & he searched online & found others who ARE using Win 7 with this MB.
He did say I was going to need a PS2 mouse because the USB mouse wouldn't work until the drivers were installed. I got an PS2 adapter.
So the mouse did work in BIOS with no issues, and we finally got the BIOS to recognize the thumb drive with Win on it, it installed the first part of Win, but after it restarted, the MB literally SHUT DOWN my keyboard and mouse so I couldn't do anything.
I was furious.
Then I said ok, get me over to the new SSD I had working win Win 7 on the other computer, we got to that screen & AGAIN, it stopped me from typing in my password. It shut down my mouse and keyboard.
Can someone help me to figure this out. I do NOT want Win 10, & this is ridiculous that this MB is stopping me.
Thanks a ton

Welcome, but there is too much rant and information thats not relevant. More information such ad messages or logs would help.

I faced a similar situation a few years ago. MSI 790FX that was fine with Win7 failed. I replaced it with MSI B450. On startup with the Win7 HDD, it went into diagnostic mode and that was it. As I recall it was due to incompatible drivers.
Well sometimes you have to go around a problem. Ultimately I found two solutions:

Replace the failed motherboard with the same kind (MSI 790FX in my case), or similar that supports Win7. Usually you can find one in the aftermarket (ebay or such), though you have to be careful about the condition it's in and do testing.
Unless you're running Windows only software (I wasn't), consider another OS. I've been running Ubuntu linux on one system for several years now without problem, and most general use software has equivalents there. And it's free.


Thanks 4 answering.
No, this had to do with the mouse & keyboard being blocked by the MB so I couldn't continue the Win installation.
The MB is brand new, nothing is failed. I said that above.
I've ordered a PS2 mouse & it should arrive tomorrow. The PS2 convertor didn't work & I'm HOPING the mouse does.
I will eventually put Linux on one of the HDs, but for now I just need a computer I can do my work on.
Not all software I use is available on Linux, & I like the software I use. I would have to figure out which distro to use b/c that's not easy although I looked at Mint once.
